# Problems compiling Haskell School of Expression on Mac, on what platform is it known to be compilable/runnable?

Tags: haskell

Any idea how one could get this code compiled below on Mac OS (Maverick)? I followed the instructions [here](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/hudak/SOE/). Other (non-graphics) part of the code seems to work in the GHCi.

If I try to run `main3book` from GHCi it crashes with segmentation fault. Maybe I could run it in a virtual machine of some kind (under VMWARE, 32 bit Windows XP)?

It would be good to know on what platform one can run the examples from this book for sure so if someone managed to run these examples recently then please let me know how.

Edit: in this [discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.beginners/9064) they mention Ubuntu where it worked. I just hope I am not the only one on the internet who is trying get these old examples running nowadays.

```
bash-3.2$ cat MyGraphics.hs 
import SimpleGraphics
main = main3book

bash-3.2$ ghc MyGraphics
[3 of 3] Compiling Main             ( MyGraphics.hs, MyGraphics.o )
Linking MyGraphics ...
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libHSGLFW-0.5.2.0.a(cocoa_joystick.o)
  "_IOIteratorNext", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libHSGLFW-0.5.2.0.a(cocoa_joystick.o)
  "_IOMasterPort", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libHSGLFW-0.5.2.0.a(cocoa_joystick.o)
  "_IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libHSGLFW-0.5.2.0.a(cocoa_joystick.o)
  "_IOServiceGetMatchingServices", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libHSGLFW-0.5.2.0.a(cocoa_joystick.o)
  "_IOServiceMatching", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libHSGLFW-0.5.2.0.a(cocoa_joystick.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You´re not the only one with this problem. There were no other solutions on the wire than yours, so I followed the advice and installed a VM and ran the code from there. Now it works! I think Paul Hudak should mention this problems in his book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved with Ubuntu 12 (32 bit version) in VMWARE Fusion.

See picture below :)

[image]